What is user ID actually used for in Optimizely isFeatureEnabled()?
I'm using the C# SDK v4 and Feature Experimentation.
I'm struggling to understand what the userID is actually used for in IsFeatureEnabled().
Can we create a rule that says if user ID = 123 the feature toggle is enabled, otherwise it's disabled?
Do we need to some how import all our user IDs into Optimizely?

Each user should have a unique ID to ensure the user stays in the same bucket for the duration of their visit (or longer, depending on requirements). So, it can basically be a random-generated ID that you keep for the duration of the session.
